# Como realizar o calculo de horas via reduce?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Então eu estou com uma pequena duvida a respeito de realizar o calculo de horas utilizando o reduce, pois até a etapa onde eu parei eu consigo retornar as horas em formato normal e agora preciso fazer a soma delas eu pensei em "quebrar"em milissegundos, mas não sei ainda como proceder, abaixo o código e print do console.

Obs: a primeira linha só coloquei por questão de contexto, esse faz parte do node onde me comunico com o banco para retornar os registros disponíveis do usuário

```js
$.get(`/usuarios/${value}/filtro/registros?year=${ano}&month=${mes}`, function(registros) {
      let inconsistencias = [];
      let horasTrabalhadasDia = [];

      registros.forEach(function(re) {
        var tste = getTime(Date.calcHrTrab(re.entrada, re.intervalo, re.retorno, re.saida))
        console.log(tste)
        if (tste == '----') {
          return null;
        }
        //console.log(re)
        horasTrabalhadasDia.push(tste);
      });


      console.log(horasTrabalhadasDia)
      //  var horasTrabalhadasDia = [];

      // registros.forEach(function (re) {
      //  horasTrabalhadasDia.push(Date.calcHrTrab(re.entrada, re.intervalo, re.retorno, re.saida));
      //console.log(horasTrabalhadasDia)
      //});
      //console.log(horasTrabalhadasDia)

      var totalHorasMes = horasTrabalhadasDia.reduce((a, p) => a + p);
      console.log(totalHorasMes)

      //console.log(registros)
```

E o array de registos é:

```js
[
  {
    "cod": 55,
    "cod_usuario": 3,
    "data": "2019-09-04T13:06:38.000Z",
    "entrada": "2019-09-04T13:06:38.000Z",
    "intervalo": null,
    "retorno": null,
    "saida": "2019-09-04T13:07:54.000Z",
    "justificativa_entrada": null,
    "justificativa_saida": null,
    "justificativa_intervalo": null,
    "justificativa_retorno": null
  },
  {
    "cod": 54,
    "cod_usuario": 3,
    "data": "2019-09-01T14:59:50.000Z",
    "entrada": "2019-09-04T13:07:35.000Z",
    "intervalo": null,
    "retorno": null,
    "saida": null,
    "justificativa_entrada": null,
    "justificativa_saida": null,
    "justificativa_intervalo": null,
    "justificativa_retorno": null
  },
  {
    "cod": 52,
    "cod_usuario": 3,
    "data": "2019-08-28T16:39:48.000Z",
    "entrada": "2019-08-28T16:39:43.000Z",
    "intervalo": "2019-08-28T17:00:00.000Z",
    "retorno": "2019-08-28T16:45:48.000Z",
    "saida": null,
    "justificativa_entrada": null,
    "justificativa_saida": null,
    "justificativa_intervalo": "Esqueceu de registrar o ponto",
    "justificativa_retorno": "Esqueceu de registrar o ponto"
  },
  {
    "cod": 51,
    "cod_usuario": 3,
    "data": "2019-08-27T15:22:56.000Z",
    "entrada": "2019-08-27T15:22:56.000Z",
    "intervalo": "2019-08-27T15:23:51.000Z",
    "retorno": "2019-08-27T15:23:59.000Z",
    "saida": "2019-08-27T15:24:06.000Z",
    "justificativa_entrada": null,
    "justificativa_saida": null,
    "justificativa_intervalo": null,
    "justificativa_retorno": null
  }
]
```

Comment: Essa imagem da consola vem de onde? podes dar um exemplo de um registo e do retorno de  `getTime(Date.calcHrTrab`?

Comment: getTime(Date.calcHrTrab é uma função que eu utilizo para calcular as horas que eu retorno do banco acho que não expliquei muito bem a respeito do meu sistema, ele é algo como um sistema de ponto eletronico vou mandar um link com as imagens para explicar melhor.
https://imgur.com/a/0r4lZrZ

Comment: Então `getTime(Date.calcHrTrab` aceita objetos Date e o que queres é que retorne o numero de milisegundos trabalhados e somar tudo, correto?

Comment: Então como vc viu no console acima, eu utilizo a função `.reduce((a, p) => a + p);` para que eu possa somar as horas retornadas, porém como visto no console, ele acaba não somando por estar no formato incorreto ele apenas concatena e o que eu preciso na realidade é somar para dar um resultado final que seria considerado as horas trabalhadas o que no caso acima daria 00:22:35, entendes?

Comment: Sim eu compreendo, isso é simples. Eu vou perguntando até ter algo mais concreto para dar uma resposta que ajude outros também. Podes colocar aqui o resultado de `console.log(JSON.stringify(registros));` logo na linha abaixo do `$.get`.

Comment: primeiro é o retorno de console.log(JSON.stringify(registros)); e o segundo é um console.log(registros) fiz esse por parecer mais organizado que o JSON
https://imgur.com/a/lRjsLdK

Comment: Coloca aqui o texto (nós ajudamos a formatar) de `console.log(JSON.stringify(registros));` que uso isso na resposta.

Comment: Não vou (nem quero :) ) copiar esse JSON de uma imagem, daí pedir para colocares aqui.

Comment: Esta aqui, não consigo colocar muito caracteres aqui.
https://pastr.io/view/7SvRHq1hbPD
Esta ficando muito extenso aqui, não seria melhor conversarmos por email ou algo assim? Não posso abrir chat aqui

Comment: Quando a saída é `null` como interpretar esses dados? há uma hora máxima? tipo 18.00, ou meia noite? ou conta para o próximo dia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes fazer isso de maneira mais simples num só `.reduce`, com algumas funções de apoio. Desaconselho vivamente acrescentar métodos ao protótipo de Date como `Date.calcHrTrab`.

Uma sugestão seria assim:

```js
const registos = [{"cod":55,"cod_usuario":3,"data":"2019-09-04T13:06:38.000Z","entrada":"2019-09-04T13:06:38.000Z","intervalo":null,"retorno":null,"saida":"2019-09-04T13:07:54.000Z","justificativa_entrada":null,"justificativa_saida":null,"justificativa_intervalo":null,"justificativa_retorno":null},{"cod":54,"cod_usuario":3,"data":"2019-09-01T14:59:50.000Z","entrada":"2019-09-04T13:07:35.000Z","intervalo":null,"retorno":null,"saida":null,"justificativa_entrada":null,"justificativa_saida":null,"justificativa_intervalo":null,"justificativa_retorno":null},{"cod":52,"cod_usuario":3,"data":"2019-08-28T16:39:48.000Z","entrada":"2019-08-28T16:39:43.000Z","intervalo":"2019-08-28T17:00:00.000Z","retorno":"2019-08-28T16:45:48.000Z","saida":null,"justificativa_entrada":null,"justificativa_saida":null,"justificativa_intervalo":"Esqueceu de registrar o ponto","justificativa_retorno":"Esqueceu de registrar o ponto"},{"cod":51,"cod_usuario":3,"data":"2019-08-27T15:22:56.000Z","entrada":"2019-08-27T15:22:56.000Z","intervalo":"2019-08-27T15:23:51.000Z","retorno":"2019-08-27T15:23:59.000Z","saida":"2019-08-27T15:24:06.000Z","justificativa_entrada":null,"justificativa_saida":null,"justificativa_intervalo":null,"justificativa_retorno":null}];


// Funções de apoio
const tempoEntreDatas = (a, b) => {
  if (!a && !b) return 0;
  return new Date(b).getTime() - new Date(a).getTime();
}

const tempoDeRegisto = (registo) => {
  const HORA_MAX_DE_SAIDA = 24;
  const entrada = new Date(registo.entrada);
  const intervalo = new Date(registo.intervalo);
  const retorno = new Date(registo.retorno);
  let saida = registo.saida;
  if (!saida) {
    saida = new Date(
      entrada.getFullYear(),
      entrada.getMonth(),
      entrada.getDate(),
      HORA_MAX_DE_SAIDA, 0, 0
    );
  }
  const duracaoDia = tempoEntreDatas(entrada, saida);
  const duracaoIntervalo = tempoEntreDatas(intervalo, retorno);
  return duracaoDia - duracaoIntervalo;
};

const msParaHHMMSS = (ms) => [
  Math.floor((ms / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24),
  Math.floor((ms / (1000 * 60)) % 60),
  Math.floor((ms / 1000) % 60)
].map(nr => nr < 10 ? '0' + nr : nr).join(':');

// O reduce
const registosTrabalhoMS = registos.reduce(
  (soma, registo) => soma + tempoDeRegisto(registo), 0
);

console.log(`O registou somou ${msParaHHMMSS(registosTrabalhoMS)}`);
```